# facebook integration in awesomemenu in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have implemented awesomemenu in my game now i want to put three buttons by which i can redirect to another page like game high score , facebook ,and volume settings

but in awesomemenu if i want to add this facebook integration than how it will work means i got sharekit project which work properly now i want that to integrate in this game

in AwesomeMenu.m file there is touch detection method in which i can recognize three button by the tag but here i can't use [[ccdirector sharedirector]replacescene:] 
Guide me what i have to write here?

```
- (void)AwesomeMenuItemTouchesEnd:(AwesomeMenuItem *)item
{
NSLog(@"%@",item);
// exclude the "add" button
if (item == _addButton) 
{
return;
}

if(item.tag==1001){

}
if(item.tag==1002){
}
if(item.tag==1003){
}
}
```

what should i have to write in this if statement? is it correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

There's a delegate function that comes with AwesomeMenu, which is: `-(void)awesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx` and let's you know which button did the user press.

To implement this, you need to:

1. set `self` as the `delegate` of the AwesomeMenu instance.
2. Add `<AwesomeMenuDelegate>` protocol to `self`.
3. implement `-(void)awesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx`.

example:

```
-(void)awesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx
{
    switch (idx) {
        case 0:
            [self Button1Pressed];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self Button2Pressed];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self Button3Pressed];
            break;
        case 3:
            [self Button4Pressed];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it's not clear. :)

Comment: where i have to add this method? -(void)awesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx